# how can i get the asked servlet in the current filter?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

(and sorry for my english, i speak french)

in the filter i'm writing, i need to know the name of the servlet asked by the user. It will allow me to check if the servlet matchs an entry of my database. 
In fact, i'm coding a restriction filter. This is how it works :

- user attempts to get the URL /users/liste linked to the 'userListe' Servlet
- a 1st filter (SimpleConnexion) checks out if the user object is defined in the httpsession ( = is the user connected ? ). If the user is connected, the 2nd filter is called, else a redirection towards the connexion page is sent.
- in the 2nd filter (AccessRights), i need name of servlet (userListe) and service method (i.e get, post, head, put, delete, ... ).

I check in the database if the entry servletName-service is defined for the current user's access rights. 
If yes, the servlet is called, else redirection towards a connexion page.

**How can I get the Current Servlet Object or name in a filter?**

With the debug tool of Eclipse, I noticed that the FilterChain object given as parameter of Filter.doFilter method contains an object servlet with the name 'userListe'. But this object is private, so i can't use it. Do u know a way to help me.

((I really need to do this job into a filter because many servlets are involved.))

Thank u for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `httpRequest.getServletPath()` to determine which servlet was called. It returns the URL of the current servlet (e.g. `/users/liste`), which is not the same as the servlet's name, but it should do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

You can use the method `httpRequest.getMethod()` to retrieve the http method used (get, post, etc.).

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String servletPath = httpRequest.getServletPath();
    String httpMethod = httpRequest.getMethod();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've already found getMethod. Thank you anyway.
As you said, the servletPath method give me the the url-pattern defined into the web.xml and not the servlet name. And this is not what I want.
But if you know a way to get servlet name from servlet path, i'll take it.

Comment: Finally i found my own solution. 

I writted a function which parse web.xml file to search the servlet i need

Answer (score 1):

If you are running version 4.0 or greater of the Servlet API there is a mapping class constructed at runtime and available to you for this purpose:

```
HttpServletMapping
```

You can pull the mapped servlet name from the request, like this:

```
String servletName = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHttpServletMapping().getServletName();
```

Comment: Updated answer to address both critiques.